# EF Where Clause with Current User Id

Tags: entity-framework

I have a ViewModel that needs to include both all the details about the current user and all the details about the Plan they're enrolled in:

```
public class SubscribeViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Plans Plan { get; set; }
    public string StripePublishableKey { get; set; }
    public string StripeToken { get; set; }
}
```

Each user has a PlanId. So what I'm trying to accomplish is something like:

`SELECT * FROM Plans WHERE Id = (SELECT PlanId FROM Users WHERE UserId = CurrentUsersId);`

My controller, thus far:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Subscribe()
{
    string CurrentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    SubscribeViewModel model = new SubscribeViewModel()
    {

        User = UserManager.FindById(CurrentUser),

        Plan = db.Plans.Where(a => a.Id == (db.Users.Where(b => b.Id == CurrentUser).Select(PlanId))
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

I'm stuck on the latter part of the Plan query, not sure how to select only the current user's PlanId.

Comment: Add your Plan model class to the question lease!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said ***Each user has a PlanId.*** So you can do as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Subscribe()
{
    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(currentUserId),

    var  plan = db.Plans.Where(a => a.Id == currentUser.PlanId).FirstOrDefault();

    SubscribeViewModel model = new SubscribeViewModel()
    {
         User = currentUser,
         Plan = plan,
         StripePublishableKey = "StripePublishableKey",
         StripeToken = "StripeToken"
    };

    return View(model);
}
```